# Активная ссылка в python kivy

Tags: python, url, kivy

Моя программа выдает на экран множество разных ссылок, мне бы хотелось узнать, как сделать их активными (чтобы на них можно было нажать и перейти на страницу в интернете)?

Comment: Что значит "активными"?

Comment: Чтобы на них можно было нажать и перейти на страницу в интернете

Answer (score 1):

```
Label:
    markup: True
    text: '[ref=]My link[/ref]'
    on_ref_press: webbrowser.open(link)
```

Comment: Спасибо,  буду пробовать